# lidR: Clipping LAS files with a polygon shapefile using clip_roi

Tags: lidar, lidr, point-cloud

I'm trying to clip a LAScatalog (containing several .las files) with a shapefile (containing multiple polygons). I tried using clip_roi function, however getting an  `Error: Z only allowed for 3 or more dimensions' in (POLYGON Z.` Here is my code:

```
polygon <- st_read("polygons.shp")

filtered_ctg <-readLAScatalog("Filtered_LAZ")
opt_output_files(filtered_cat) <- "plot_a_{ID}"
clipped_laz <- clip_roi(filtered_ctg, polygon)
```

I also tried using geometry instead of the shapefile by adding a st_geometry()

```
geometry <- st_geometry(polygon)
```

However, this time I got an `Error in if (ncol(sf) > 1) { : argument is of length zero`

Comment: It seems that your polygons are 3D with a Z dimension. Try to get rid of Z with `st_zm`